# How to register a goal in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

[image]

I have recently started buying google ad for some promotion.

Ultimately I want to drive signup by these ads.

In acquisition, I can find this set of figures of my campaign.

There is this 'Goal 1: create an account'.

My questions are

1) I don't know how I can register a successful user signup as 'Goal 1' in google analytics.

2) There are 12 session for this campaign. But when I switched to AUDIENCE-> User Explorer with the same campaign as criteria, there is only one user. How does these 12 sessions mapped to the one user?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most usual way to set a goal for a sign-up would be to use the url of the final thank-you or confirmation page as the destination page.
Go to Admin > Goals > New Goal> then give it a name and choose Destination as the type of Goal.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it programmatically? e.g. after signup can I call a certain javascript function to create a user profile similar to mixpanel's people?